# Personalized mailchimp RSS to EMAIL based on profile fields options

Tags: rss, mailchimp, email-notifications

my website has different categories (eg: food, travel, health..), and different content types (news, video, events, etc).
I need my user to register to updates according to their preferences.

In mailchimp, I thought of creating a RSS to EMAIL campaign with a uber-rss containing everything, then using merge-tags conditions to filter only the content corresponding to the user's preference (profile fields options).

The problem of doing so is that the RSS email will be sent every time there is something new in the RSS, even if the user will not have matching content to her preferences, so she may receive an empty email.

any other idea?